# MYSQL duplicate rows with different id's and created_at column

Tags: mysql

I want to find duplicate rows from table, All columns are same except id and created_at column.
Conditions for rows are

```
 1. rows are consecutive i-e id always differ by 1 
 2. created at column can differ maximum by 10s.
```

is there a way to write mysql query to find these rows?

Comment: GROUP BY {list of all columns except id and created_at}, and then check the COUNT …?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: There are several ways to approach this. Have you tried anything yet? I'd probably use `EXISTS` to see if for a record exists another with ID+1 or ID-1 with the same data and the timestamp not more than 10s different. Doesn't sound too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table a 
WHERE id= (SELECT MAX(id) 
           FROM table b 
           WHERE a.created_at=b.created_at)
```